# IDA plugin to show xrefs to virtual functions?

Tags: ida

I'm analyzing a C++ PE binary with its debug symbols using IDA 7.3 w/ the decompiler.

I'm using the HexRaysPyTools plugin to get the xrefs to class fields, but it doesn't show xrefs to virtual functions.

I want to know if there is an existing similar plugin that can build the xref list for calls to virtual functions statically (ie. without running the code).

As far as I can understand the behavior of HexRaysPyTools, it should be trivial to do that as the IDA decompiler already recognize virtual function calls when decompiling, I just need it to store the xref list to virtual functions just as HexRaysPyTools does with member fields.

Comment: im not going to start a new topic as this one is perfectly related to my question and is reletively new.
i am searching for good vtable/RTTI tools. i came across the ida_medigate (mentioned above) but i cant get it working. anyone can help me with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact this is not as “trivial” as one might think.

However there was a plug-in submitted to this year’s plug-in contest that *might* work:

https://www.hex-rays.com/contests_details/contest2020/#ida_medigate

https://github.com/medigate-io/ida_medigate